# Azure Dashboard logs column is not present in add filter of dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-dashboard

I have written KQL query to fetch logs from application insights and pinned the logs to azure dashboard, however when I am trying to add global filter on column through Azure Dashboard's add filter, I am not able to as column is missing from the list.
Column Name screenshot :- [image]

available columns in Add filter screenshot :- [image]

CRMStatusCode column has values.

Answer (score 1):

***I have tried to reproduce in my environment and i successfully got the filters***

- ***Firstly, I have pinned logs to dashboard***
- ***Then I added a metrics chart and it will take time to get Filters then it will reflect and be visible***
- ***Then when i click on filter I get the below filters***

[image]

***References taken from:***

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards#set-and-override-dashboard-filters

Comment: sorry, it did not work, I was using the column in project section but then had to use extend